# Access static variable in session [Non Static]

Tags: c#, variables, session, static, non-static

I have been using the session in static methods by simply using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID+...;
```

But is it possible to make unique session key by adding static variable in the same?

**Update:**
I don't get an error, in fact it works, its that when two tabs are opened up, due to static variable, the session of first tab is called in the event of a second tab, as some how I am not able to refresh the session variable.

The method in which I am creating session is actually static and Ids etc accessed by the same same method needs to be static.

I simply need a hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Cannot add static into non static (something of this sort).` - is not an error message i've ever come across. Please post the **exact** error message and the line of code that threw it

Comment: @ DGibbs: I have updated my question now. This is the problem I face.

Comment: Could you clarify more because it doesn't make sense to me. You want your session and ids to be static if the same method name is called but you want a separate session per tab? There's a contradiction in what you're asking.